# How do I specify how many ticks to print along the x-axis in matplotlib?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, graphing

I am currently working on an assignment where it is required that we print the date on the x-axis of our plotted graph. We're just learning how to use matplotlib and numpy and I'm just a bit confused on how to specify the distribution of the tick marks on the x-axis. To be more clear, I have data in arrays for a 3 year period, or 1095 days and the dates range from 1/1/2015 to 12/31/2017 so there is clearly not enough space to plot each and every day. I just need some clarification to maybe space it out by every thirty days or so just so that the graph is actually readable.

I have tried to research this and I have found some solutions but it would be extremely obvious that I copied code, as the solutions online are far too in depth to achieve this outcome. Therefore, I am turning to stackoverflow for a potentially simpler solution to my problem.

```
temp_avg = np.array([])
date = np.array([])
```

These two arrays include 1095 variables each, the date array starts with "1/1/2015" ending with "12/31/2017" including every date in between and the temp_avg array includes several integer variables.

```
mat.figure()
mat.subplot(1,2,1)
mat.xlabel("Date")
mat.ylabel("Average Temperature")
mat.plot(date, temp_avg)
```

I imported matplotlib.pyplot as mat which is the explanation for mat.(whatever).

My apoligies as I would post the image, but this account doesn't have enough reputation to do so apparently.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/v93uu.jpg

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Convert your dates to `datetime`, then matplotlib will automatically find nice ticks and labels for you.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I'm sorry for not completely understanding what you mean, can you explain a little more how I would do that?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I actually read a little more about it and that would require another import which I don't think I would be able to use.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The `datetime` module is part of python, so you can just use it. Matplotlib imports datetime anyways, so that's definitely not a problem.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest even if it's included, I was looking for a simpler change that would fix this problem, but if that's not possible I'll have to find another way. I just can't use that because it's something we haven't touched on. We've only really looked at the intro to pyplot documentation and not much else.

Comment: That reads as if you cannot ride a bicycle because you only just started taking driving lessons. Using dates as strings is completely unreasonable - don't do it. The [matplotlib documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/dates_api.html) tells you what to do instead, namely to use `datetime` objects.